# JQuery: Find submitted search string in an element. Load into div the element containing that string

Tags: jquery, search, load, contains, attr

Through JQuery I am creating some search functionality so that on click of the search submit button, the code should do the following:

1. Pass the search string into a variable.
2. Find any section elements containing the search string variable and get that section's ID attribute.
3. Load into a specific div a different page's url, which targets the ID of the containing section, so that the div loads only the section containing the matching string, and not the entire html page. This other html page is just another page that would be on my domain. It contains a body with several section elements, each with a unique ID and some text. It does link to the JQuery file in its script tag.

I am able to achieve #1 of the above but there appears to be an issue with #2 in my code, as #3 the loading never occurs. I added an alert for debugging which displayed 'undefined' when returning the foundId variable storing the sections with the matching string. As to the loading of the url itself, this url should be able to load into the div just fine as when I attempted to load the entire html page instead of just the matching section, that worked. I do want to use load() instead of append() for this.

Appreciate if any of you lovely people out there can point out the error in my ways:

main.html:

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <form action="#" id="search-form" method="get">
    <fieldset>
      <input type="search" id="search-box" name="search" value=""/>
      <input type="submit" id="search-submit" value="Show me"/>                 
    </fieldset>
  </form>
  <div id="info_display"></div>
</div>
```

example snippet from info.html (the secondary page that should load into div on main.html)

```html
 <body>
    <section id="content-good">
      <header>Good Thing</header>
      <p>Description of thing</p>
    </section>
    <section id="content-great">
       <header>Great Thing</header>
       <p>Description of thing</p>
    </section>
    <section id="content-best">
       <header>Best Thing</header>
       <p>Description of thing</p>
    </section>
 </body>
```

JQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
     var query;
     var foundId;
      $('#search-submit').click(function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          query = $("#search-box").val();
          if (query.length > 0) {
            foundId = $('section:contains('+query+')').attr('id');
            $("#info_display").load('info.html #' + foundId);
          }
          else {
            alert("Oops, you forgot to enter a search term.");
          }
      });
});
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code did the trick:

```
 $('#search-submit').click(function(e){
    var query = $("#search-box").val();
    e.preventDefault();
    if (query.length > 0) {
        $.get('info.html', function(html){
        var $html = $(html);
        var $match = $html.find(':contains('+query+')').parent('section');
            if ($match.length > 0) {
            $("#info_display").empty().append($match);
            }
            else {
                $("#info_display").empty().append('<p>No result was found!</p>');
            }
        }, 'html');
    }
    else {
    $("#info_display").empty().append('<p>Oops, you forgot to enter a search term.</p>');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `foundId = $('section:contains('+query+')').attr('id');` will not return anything since the `section` elements are not present in the `main.html`

Try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#search-submit').click(function(e){
        var query = $("#search-box").val();;
        e.preventDefault();

        if (query.length > 0) {
            $.get('info.html', function(html){
                var $html = $(html);
                $("#info_display").empty().append($html.find('section:contains('+query+')').first())
            }, 'html')
        }
        else {
            alert("Oops, you forgot to enter a search term.");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi Arun, thanks so much for the response. I was able to get it to work after some tweeks to your sample. For some reason using 'section:contains was still not producing any result when used exactly as above, even after I removed the extra ; after val(). I also tried to add a semicolon after },'html') in ln 10 but to no avail. I will post the code that worked. Essentially I searched on :contains instead of the section element only and this did the trick.